# Multiplying a series and a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, series

suppose that I have a series of amounts (let think to moneys to make it more intertesting) and I want to split those amounts among people (franco, franchino and gianmarco).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
moneys = pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':10, 'd':9, 'e':7})
percentages = pd.DataFrame({'franco':[0.1],'franchino':[0.5],'gianmarco':[0.4]})
```

---

[image]

In this case, I want to obtain a matrix 5x3 as follows:

[image]

Is there a function similar to pd.multiply or .dot that does the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.dot`:

```
moneys.to_frame().dot(percentages)

   franchino  franco  gianmarco
a        0.5     0.1        0.4
b        1.5     0.3        1.2
c        5.0     1.0        4.0
d        4.5     0.9        3.6
e        3.5     0.7        2.8
```

This is the same as your expected result, with the last two columns permuted.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
In [5868]: pd.DataFrame(percentages.values * moneys.values[:, np.newaxis], 
                        columns=percentages.columns, index=moneys.index)
Out[5868]:
   franchino  franco  gianmarco
a        0.5     0.1        0.4
b        1.5     0.3        1.2
c        5.0     1.0        4.0
d        4.5     0.9        3.6
e        3.5     0.7        2.8
```

Details

```
In [5869]: percentages.values * moneys.values[:, np.newaxis]
Out[5869]:
array([[ 0.5,  0.1,  0.4],
       [ 1.5,  0.3,  1.2],
       [ 5. ,  1. ,  4. ],
       [ 4.5,  0.9,  3.6],
       [ 3.5,  0.7,  2.8]])
```